# JavaFx: How to Animate an Inherited Node?

Tags: animation, javafx, transition

How do I animate an object of a class, that is inherited from ImageView, from within the class definition?

My Code:

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView{

public CustomImageView(String imageLocation){

    this.setImage(new Image(imageLocation));
    FadeTransition fadeIn = new FadeTransition();
    fadeIn.setDuration(new Duration(2000));
    fadeIn.setFromValue(0);
    fadeIn.setToValue(1);
    fadeIn.setNode(this);
    fadeIn.play();

    fadeIn.setOnFinished(ae->System.out.println("Finished!"));
    }
}
```

The code displays the message when the animation is finished but the node itself is not animated.

Answer (score 0):

Although your code should theoretically work, a slightly better approach would be:

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {
    public CustomImageView(String imageLocation){
        this.setImage(new Image(imageLocation));
        this.setOpacity(0); // completely transparent when created
    }

    // can play anytime on demand
    public void playFadeInAnimation(Runnable action) {
        FadeTransition fadeIn = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(2), this);
        fadeIn.setFromValue(0);
        fadeIn.setToValue(1);
        fadeIn.setOnFinished(e -> action.run());
        fadeIn.play();
    }
}
```

Somewhere else, where you are using the `CustomImageView`

```
CustomImageView view = new CustomImageView(...);
someParent.getChildren().add(view); // display on screen
view.playFadeInAnimation(...);      // play animation
```